# a method to modify a list in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I don't have the right method for the for loop I have a list that looks like this

```
print(c)
OutPut: ['vendredi 6 aoû.',
 'Monaco',
 '1 - 1',
 'Nantes',
 'samedi 7 aoû.',
 'Lyon',
 '1 - 1',
 'Brest',
 'Troyes',
 '1 - 2',
 'Paris-SG']
```

```
li = []

for x in c:
    p = x.split()
    if len(p) == 3:
        li.extend(p)
    else:
        li.append(p)
print(li)
OutPut:
[['vendredi', '6', 'aoû.', ['Monaco'], '1', '-', '1', ['Nantes'], 'samedi', '7', 'aoû.', ['Lyon'], '1', '-', '1', ['Brest'], ['Troyes'], '1', '-', '2', ['Paris-SG'], 'dimanche', '8', 'aoû.', ['Rennes'], '1', '-', '1', ['Lens'], ['Saint-Étienne'], '1', '-', '1', ['Lorient'], ['Strasbourg'], '0', '-', '2', ['Angers'], ['Bordeaux'], '0', '-', '2', ['Clermont'], ['Nice'], '0', '-', '0', ['Reims'], ['Metz'], '3', '-', '3', ['Lille'], ['Montpellier'], '2', '-', '3', ['Marseille']]
```

I would like to have something like that out

```
[['vendredi', '6', 'aoû.'],
 ['Monaco', '1', '-', '1', 'Nantes'],
 ['samedi', '7', 'aoû.'],
 ['Lyon', '1', '-', '1', 'Brest'],
 ['Troyes','1', '-', '2', 'Paris-SG'],
 ['dimanche', '8', 'aoû.'],
 ['Rennes', '1', '-', '1', 'Lens'],
 ['Saint-Étienne', '1', '-', '1', 'Lorient']]
```

then I will integrate this list in a dataframe.

PS: Forgive me for asking the wrong question, I'm just starting out, I don't yet have the best practices ;-)

Comment: That's nice. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Comment: There is no regularity i can see. Why do you want it like that? what did you do to get the lists in the first case. what did you code to fix your initial list. what is your problem? [mre]?

Comment: What is `c`? It is not defined

Comment: I have scrap a site of statistics on the foot, that's how I got the data.

Comment: is my question better now?

Comment: How can you possibly know how this should be arranged?  Even as a human being, what criteria would you use to decide how these things should be arranged?

Comment: I want it to be organized this way because I plan to give them a colone name when I put it in my dataframe

Comment: *I want it to organized this way* -- WHAT way?  Look at your incoming data stream.  How would a computer know which lines need to be handled differently?  I assume the "vendredi" and "samedi" lines are dates.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f=False
final_list=[]
current=[]
l=['vendredi', '6', 'aoû.',
['Monaco'], '1', '-', '1', ['Nantes'], 
'samedi', '7', 'aoû.', 
['Lyon'], '1', '-', '1', ['Brest'], 
['Troyes'], '1', '-', '2', ['Paris-SG'], 
'dimanche', '8', 'aoû.', 
['Rennes'], '1', '-', '1', ['Lens'], 
['Saint-Étienne'], '1', '-', '1', ['Lorient'], 
['Strasbourg'], '0', '-', '2', ['Angers'], 
['Bordeaux'], '0', '-', '2', ['Clermont'], 
['Nice'], '0', '-', '0', ['Reims'], 
['Metz'], '3', '-', '3', ['Lille'], 
['Montpellier'], '2', '-', '3', ['Marseille']]

for i in l:
    if type(i) != list:
        current.append(i)
    else:
        if f==False:
            if len(current)!=0:
                final_list.append(current)
            current=i
            f=True
        else:
            current.extend(i)
            final_list.append(current)
            current=[]
            f=False
```

output

```
[['vendredi', '6', 'aou.'], 
['Monaco', '1', '-', '1', 'Nantes'], 
['samedi', '7', 'aou.'], 
['Lyon', '1', '-', '1', 'Brest'], 
['Troyes', '1', '-', '2', 'Paris-SG'], 
['dimanche', '8', 'aou.'], 
['Rennes', '1', '-', '1', 'Lens'], 
['Saint-Etienne', '1', '-', '1', 'Lorient'], 
['Strasbourg', '0', '-', '2', 'Angers'], 
['Bordeaux', '0', '-', '2', 'Clermont'], 
['Nice', '0', '-', '0', 'Reims'], 
['Metz', '3', '-', '3', 'Lille'], 
['Montpellier', '2', '-', '3', 'Marseille']]
```

and this code for other input data

```
c = ['vendredi 6 aou.',
 'Monaco',
 '1 - 1',
 'Nantes',
 'samedi 7 aou.',
 'Lyon',
 '1 - 1',
 'Brest',
 'Troyes',
 '1 - 2',
 'Paris-SG']

final_list=[]

i=0

while (i<len(c)):
    if c[i][-1]=='.':
        final_list.append(c[i].split())
        i=i+1
    else:
        current=[c[i]]
        current.extend(c[i+1].split())
        current.append(c[i+2])
        final_list.append(current)
        i=i+3

final_list
```

output

```
[['vendredi', '6', 'aou.'], 
['Monaco', '1', '-', '1', 'Nantes'], 
['samedi', '7', 'aou.'], 
['Lyon', '1', '-', '1', 'Brest'], 
['Troyes', '1', '-', '2', 'Paris-SG']]
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo Corrected the input and wrote the code for two options

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask, as strange as it is.  Like you, I rely on the fact that the date lines have 3 parts, but I check that the middle item is a number, to distinguish it from the scores.  I changed the extended characters in your data, since my Windows system didn't like them.  You can fix that.

```
from pprint import pprint
c = ['vendredi 6 aou.',
 'Monaco',
 '1 - 1',
 'Nantes',
 'samedi 7 aou.',
 'Lyon',
 '1 - 1',
 'Brest',
 'Troyes',
 '1 - 2',
 'Paris-SG']
pprint(c)

outlist = []
for line in c:
    p = line.split()
    if len(p) == 3 and p[1].isdigit():
        # This is a date.
        outlist.append( p )
        outlist.append( [] )
    elif len(outlist[-1]) == 5:
        outlist.append( p )
    else:
        outlist[-1].extend( p )

pprint(outlist)
```

Output:

```
['vendredi 6 aou.',
 'Monaco',
 '1 - 1',
 'Nantes',
 'samedi 7 aou.',
 'Lyon',
 '1 - 1',
 'Brest',
 'Troyes',
 '1 - 2',
 'Paris-SG']
[['vendredi', '6', 'aou.'],
 ['Monaco', '1', '-', '1', 'Nantes'],
 ['samedi', '7', 'aou.'],
 ['Lyon', '1', '-', '1', 'Brest'],
 ['Troyes', '1', '-', '2', 'Paris-SG']]
```